# Tutorial to make custom google maps form/find location by zip code?

Tags: javascript

I need to create a form where there will be input box and below google map. User will be required to  type his/her post code then when click btn pin will drop on correct location. Does anyone could point me at right direction where i can find such a example or tutorial how that could be done.

Comment: did you even search for the answer first? also, "can anyone help please" is not a title that will bring people to the page.

Comment: Btw, this is not a title: "Can anyone help please". This is not a forum this is Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the google maps API, specifically the geocoder, to map a location to a point on the map, a code example is here: http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v2-geocoder-tool.html